# kernel module killed on using insmod

Tags: c, linux, file, io, linux-kernel

I am trying to implement cat command as a kernel module. I know file i/o should not be done in a kernel module,. Every time I use `insmod module.ko` I  get the output as `killed` . How can I fix it? Also how can I improve the code?

 kernel version - 4.4

Code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h> 
#include <linux/fcntl.h> 
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/init.h> 
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/file.h> 

static char* argv[10];
static int argc = 1;
module_param_array(argv, int, &argc , 0);

static void cat(int f, char *s)
{
    char buf[8192];
    struct file *file;
    loff_t pos = 0;
    long n;
    mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

    while((n = vfs_read(f, buf, (long)sizeof buf, &pos)) > 0) 
    {
        //write(1, buf, n);
        file = fget(f);
        if (file) {
            vfs_write(file, buf, (long)sizeof buf, &pos);
            fput(file);
        }


    }
    set_fs(old_fs);
}

static void __init hello_init(void)
{
    int f, i;
    if(argc == 1)
        cat(0, "<stdin>");
    else for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        f = filp_open(argv[i], O_RDONLY, 0);
        if(f < 0)
            printk("error");
        else{
            cat(f, argv[i]);
            filp_close(f);
        }
    }
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

Here is a simplified version of the above code which just reads a file. On commenting out the `vfs_read` part, I'm able to insmod it, but with `vfs_read` it shows killed.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

static void read_file(char *filename)
{
  int fd;
  char buf[1];
  loff_t f_pos = 0;

  mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
  set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

  fd = filp_open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
  if (fd >= 0) {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG);
    while (vfs_read(fd, buf, 1, &f_pos) == 1) //if this
      printk("%c", buf[0]);  //and this is removed I'm able to insmod it
    printk("\n");
    sys_close(fd);
  }
  set_fs(old_fs);
}

static int __init init(void)
{
  read_file("/etc/shadow");
  return 0;
}

static void __exit exit(void)
{ }

module_init(init);
module_exit(exit);
```

Comment: Have you tried to **debug** you code, for determine **which line of code crashes**? For debug kernel code you may add `printk()` calls after certain points. Also, if code crashes, `dmesg` may give additional information about that.

Comment: dmesg gives RIP  [<ffffffff8120d165>] vfs_read+0x5/0x130 and fbcon_switch: detected unhandled fb_set_par error

Comment: Which branch in your `hello_init` function is executed? (Is it `cat(0)`, or `cat(f)`)? Note, that your module accepts **array of pointers**, which is probably not what you expect. That is, `argv[i]` is a pointer to .. garbage, and dereferencing it (e.g. in `filp_open()` call) is a **definite error**.

Comment: Well, simplified version is clear. The first thing: `filp_open()` returns `struct file*` (not an `int`),  and cheking for success should be `!IS_ERR(f)`. If `filp_open` successfull, you may pass value it returns to `vfs_read()`. Closing the file is performed with `fput(f)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things ...

You're trying to do all this from the module init callback.

`argc/argv` have nothing in them, so that's a problem (i.e. you could get a segfault).

You *could* hardwire `argc/argv` with valid values, but you'd have to recompile and reload the driver with the different files you want to cat.

But it might be better to accept a module parameter and split it up with a `strtok` equivalent to populate your `argv`. This is the closest thing to an `argv` equivalent for a driver [which doesn't really exist in exactly the same way as it does for `main` in an application].

You wouldn't have to recompile the module, but, you would *still* have to reload it each time (giving `insmod` a different argument each time)

However, the real/correct way to do this would be, in the module init, to register your driver as a character device using the standard mechanism. And, likewise, unregister it in the module cleanup routine.

Then, create a `/dev` entry (e.g. `/dev/mycat`).

From an application, open `/dev/mycat`, and write a list of files you want cat'ed to the file descriptor, one per line.

Have the driver's `write` callback routine, parse down the data in the buffer you're passed (i.e. as if you were implementing your own `fgets` in userspace), and process the list it gets, performing the cat operation on each file.

Rather than creating a `/dev` entry, it *might* be easier to create a `/proc` entry (e.g. `/proc/mycat`)--YMMV

The actual mechanism to communicate the file list to the driver is arbitrary. You could use an `AF_UNIX` socket, a named pipe, hook up to a SysV message queue, etc. but the `/dev` or `/proc` solution is probably easier.

---

**UPDATE:**

> There seems to be another problem in vfs_read. dmesg gives RIP [] vfs_read+0x5/0x130 and fbcon_switch: detected unhandled fb_set_par error

Amongst other things, you are passing an `int` as the first arg to `vfs_read`. The first arg needs to be `struct file *` [just like `vfs_write`].

*Note:* If you're building the driver using the standard mechanism, this would have compiled with `-Wall` and this would have been flagged at compile time.

Also, you're trying to write [the cat output] to the same file you're reading from, even though you opened it with `O_RDONLY` (i.e. equivalent to userspace `cat foobar > foobar`). That's because, for the `vfs_write`, you did `file = fget(f)`. What you really wanted to do was `file = fget(1)`

For both `vfs_read` and `vfs_write`, you need `fget/fput` pairings. And, they need to be *separate*:

```
file_in = fget(f);
file_out = fget(1);

// read/write loop ...
while (1) {
    ...
}

fput(file_in);
fput(file_out);
```

You do *not* want to put `buf` on the stack. This produces a race condition. The [kernel] thread could migrate to another processor while I/O is still pending on the `vfs_read` [AFAIK]. Other drivers that do similar stuff use `kmalloc` to get the buffer [and `kfree` to free it].

Comment: Thanks a lot. There seems to be another problem in vfs_read. dmesg gives RIP [<ffffffff8120d165>] vfs_read+0x5/0x130 and fbcon_switch: detected unhandled fb_set_par error